# Text no displaying properly in Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I wanted to print the user reviews of a webpage along with the ratings given by them, i tried the below code

```
Elements links = doc.select("p.s_desc,span.s_rating_overal");
    //Elements links1 = doc.select();
    //System.out.println(links.next());
    ListIterator iter= links.listIterator();
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
    //String test= iter.next().text();
    System.out.println("\n"+iter.next());
    System.out.println(iter.next()+"\n\n");


    }
```

The problem is that the output is coming along with the tag.

```
<span class="s_rating_overal">5.3</span>
<p class="s_desc">You don't need a load of explanation on why this phone changed
 the market and set the standard, though the ties to AT&amp;T and Apple are way
 too strong to truly enjoy this device. &nbsp;The screen and style are now a bit
 outdated and the lack of customization make you feel like you are a cow in the t
 he big heard of i ecosystem. &nbsp;The ui is still probably the best there is bu
   t, come on its time for a face lift.</p>
```

How can i get only the text in-between the tags
thanks in advance

if i use iter.next().text();, i get the following error

```
Crawler.java:44: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method text()
location: class java.lang.Object
            System.out.println("\n"+iter.next().text());
                                             ^
Crawler.java:45: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method text()
location: class java.lang.Object
            System.out.println(iter.next().text()+"\n\n");
                                        ^
2 errors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `iter.next()` return `Element` instances. Then you concatenate the `Element` instance with a String, so the `toString()` method will be called.

The `toString()` method of the `Element` class return the tag along with the content.
If you want only the content of the element, you should use the `text()` method.

Comment: Ok, it's just a compilation error because you didn't specify the type of your ListIterator and the compiler can't know the type of `iter.next()`. If you use `ListIterator<Element> iter= links.listIterator();` your code would probably compile correctly.